# Errors with PHP/MYSQL dropdown lists displaying correct item information

Tags: php, html, mysql

At the moment I'm practicing HTML/PHP/MySQL and I am working on a small project.

I created a page that would allow the user to read data from the records found in a MySQL table. The user would click on the values dropdown list via PHP form.

The database is for a shop and has 1 table. the Table is called 'product'. When I click on the Dropdown List for a product ID then the data from the product ID will display on the pages.

I am attempting to embed this PHP code into an php file. It shows all the data, that is not what I want. I want to allow the user  to pick any item from the dropdown, and then when the User picks one of the items it will show the table on the PHP pages.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
        <br>
        <br>
        <?php
        //load_data_select  
        function fill_settlement($conn) {
            $output = '';
            $sqlDropDownSettlementID = "SELECT  * FROM `settlements` where total_amount";
            $DropDownSettlementID = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlDropDownSettlementID);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($DropDownSettlementID)) {
                $output .= '<option value="' . $row["settlement_id"] . '">' . $row["settlement_id"] . '</option>';

            }
            return $output;
        }
        function fill_product($connect) {
            $output = '';
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `settlements` where total_amount";
            $dropdownresult = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dropdownresult)) {
                $output .= '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">';
                $output .= '<tr>';
                $output .= '<td>' . $row["sku"] . '</td>';
                $output .= '<td>' . $row["settlement_start_date"] . '</td>';
                $output .= '<td>' . $row["settlement_end_date"] . '</td>';
                $output .= '<td>' . $row["currency"] . '</td>';
                $output .= '<td>' . $row["total_amount"] . '</td>';
                $output .= '</tr>';
                $output .= '</table>';

            }
            return $output;
        }

        ?>  

        <div class="container">  
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Settlement ID</label>
             <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control" name="Settlement" id="Settlement">  
                <option value="">Show All Product</option>  
                <?php echo fill_settlement($conn); ?>  
            </select> 
             </div>
            <br><br>  
            <div class="row" id="show_product">  
                <?php echo fill_product($conn); ?>  
            </div> 

        </div>
```

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoVLW.png)

I am able to get the data on the dropdown, but I cannot get the correct data when I click an item from the dropdown, I want the correct data to populate on the screen.

I did search on Google for help or advice but I cannot find the right information.

Comment: You need to use javascript or Jquery to dynamically change #show_product

Comment: Ahhh, Got it. I fixed this issue. thanks for your help Mattigins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

- You put your SELECT in a form.  The user selects a value and presses submit.  That sends the selection to the action page you defined in your form.  That action page takes the selection, build a query to extract data from the database and shows the results to the user.
- When your user selects a value, you perform an AJAX to update the page on the fly.  The user does not need to press a submit button.  AJAX calls a PHP script.  That PHP script extracts the data from the database and returns the result in a format you need to display the details.

Both methods are explained here: 
Forms: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
AJAX: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Ahhh, Got it. I fixed this issue. thanks for your help Nic.

Comment: as it similar as this

Comment: @StevenSmith: if the answer is the one you were looking for, click the check mark on the left to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a careful look at your code. The first red flag should be that you use the same query for getting **all** the options and also a **single** product.

Your `fill_product` method has no parameter to identify **which** product you want.

So first I would suggest you look up on how html forms work.
A basic workflow of your page should be like:

1. Select a settlement from the select box. You got this mostly covered but with no form to send the user selection back to the server.
2. Send the selection to the server and process the form. The form data will be passed to your php script by a superglobal in the form of $_POST["Settlement"] or $_GET["Settlement"], you can read up on the differences between POST and GET.
3. Add an argument to your `fill_product` method for settlement_id and change the query `where` clause to fetch a single row that the user selected.

As the details on how to pass the selection to your server you have several choices- POST/GET form is the most simple of choices. Or if you want to be fancy you can look into javascript and AJAX which is more advanced.